# Redux state partially revert back with next action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have this problem with my redux store.
FYI, these are two reducers i have (of many else):

```
export const WellPotential = (state={data:[],success:true,sql:'',error:null,loading:false},{type,payload}) => {
    switch(type) {
        case 'Well:Potential:Set':
            return Object.assign({},payload,{loading:false})
        case 'Well:Setup':
            return {data:[],success:true,sql:'',error:null,loading:true}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
export const WellTest = (state={data:[],success:true,sql:'',error:null,loading:false},{type,payload}) => {
    switch(type) {
        case 'Well:Test:SET':
            return Object.assign({},{loading:false},payload)
        case 'Well:Setup':
            return Object.assign({},{data:[],success:true,sql:'',error:null,loading:true})
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I am building an app with electron platform with react with redux as the front-end.
This actions happen after some data retrieval sent back to the front-end side.
As the first action dispatched the action **'Well:Test:Set'** we can see in the redux dev tools that the state was updated. Here is the log:
[image: State diff when Well:Test:Set action dispatched]

Then this happens when the action **'Well:Potential:Set'** dispatched:
[image: State diff when Well:Potential:Set action dispatched]

The data property of **WellTest** reducer got erased thus make the data property an empty array. And you can see no other mutation was made between the dispatches
I used redux thunk as middleware too.

Could someone enlighten me what went wrong?

Comment: I suspect your WellTest reducer returns the default state value you defined as function parameter : "export const WellTest = (state={data:[]..."
Try to debug with break points in your IDE if possible or in chrome with sourcemaps

Comment: I don't think so, as the state was actually modified. Other properties of WellTest was updated and stayed the same after Well:Potential:Set dispatch, only the data property got cleared

Comment: Does the following do the trick? `return Object.assign(state,payload,{loading:false})` Probably need that for all action handlers.

Comment: I tried, but didn't work either